# Saving image to the user’s contacts with Cordova Contacts plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, contacts

I seem to be having trouble saving an image to the user’s contacts with the Cordova Contacts plugin on Android.  Here is my code:

```
var contact = navigator.contacts.create();

// data.photo is a valid base64-encoded string.
contact.photos[0] = {
  "type": "base64",
  "value": data.photo
};

contact.save(function() {
  alert(“Contact saved.”);
}
```

This works perfectly on iOS but I can’t save an image on Android no matter what I try.  The `data.photo` value is a valid base64-encoded string that WILL show up as an image when pasted into a URL bar.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about that unsupported to save type base64.

You can found out that there is no type of base64 in ContactAccessorSdk5.java, which location is in Project folder in 'Platform/android/build/src/org/apache/cordova/contacts/ContactAccessorSdk5.java'

base64 of image data format start with 'data:'. so, you can modify getPathFromUri(String path) in the 'ContactAccessorSdk5.java' file for saving image data base64.

you can refer in 'https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/jTMu9Azjaa8/ywQMMEcoS1YJ'

or my GitHub below.

https://github.com/CordovaExam/Contacts

You can get it if you get there, there is more detail information.

```
private InputStream getPathFromUri(String path) throws IOException {

        if (path.startsWith("data:")) { // data:image/png;base64,[ENCODED_IMAGE]
            String dataInfos = path.substring(0, path.indexOf(',')); // data:image/png;base64
            dataInfos = dataInfos.substring(dataInfos.indexOf(':') + 1); // image/png;base64
            String baseEncoding = dataInfos.substring(dataInfos.indexOf(';') + 1); // base64
            if("base64".equalsIgnoreCase(baseEncoding)) {
                String img = path.substring(path.indexOf(',') + 1); // [ENCODED_IMAGE]
                byte[] encodedData = img.getBytes();
                ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedData, 0, encodedData.length);
                Base64InputStream base64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(byteArrayInputStream, Base64.DEFAULT);
                return base64InputStream;
            } else {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Could not decode image. The found base encoding is " + baseEncoding);

            }
        }
        if (path.startsWith("content:")) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
            return mApp.getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        }

        if (path.startsWith("http:") || path.startsWith("https:") || path.startsWith("file:")) {

            URL url = new URL(path);
            return url.openStream();
        }
        else {
            return new FileInputStream(path);
        }
    }
```